# In Visual Studio Code (VSCode) how can I quickly fold all blocks on the same level of my cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is a shortcut or plugin that can be used to fold all the blocks of code that are at the same level of the block that my cursor is on, I tried `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and then used `Fold Level 3` and etc... it kinda gets the job done but, I was wondering if there is a quicker way so that I could just **fold all blocks that are at the same level of the current block which I'm editing**. So it doesn't require me to count each time. Any ideas or plugins that can get the job done?

Comment: use the fold key bindings

Comment: @rioV8 can you explain a little more? is that a plugin? thanks in advance!

Comment: if you use the command palette you see the key bindings